# NSIS Installer showing weird black mark

Tags: user-interface, text, installation, nsis

See the circled area in the image below:

[image]

What is that and how do I get rid of it?

I'm using NSIS to build the installer.

Comment: Is the name really that secret? It just makes it harder for me to tell which parts of it are getting cut off and where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name is really long then you need to define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE_3LINES:

```
Name "blah blah blah Compatibility blah blah blah blah blah"

!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Comment: Hey @Anders, this was it! We had the title too long! much appreciated